# Can an encoding incompatible with ASCII encoding be set as a default encoding in Java?

Tags: java, encoding

Most of the encodings in use encode ASCII characters identically. This means that, if I know that a String can be encoded by ASCII encoding, then I don't need to bother and can use any such encoding. Further, if the system default encoding has this 'ASCII compatibility' property, I can safely use `new String(bytes)` for bytes representing ASCII strings.

But there are encodings (for example, EBCDIC) that are incompatible with ASCII.

Can such encoding be set as default in Java?

Comment: In theory, any encoding could be set as the default encoding; e.g. `-Dfile.encoding=EBCDIC` ... assuming that `EBCDIC` is recognized.  (Actually, it isn't, but Cp1140 is ... almost EBCDIC.)

Comment: Not very many encodings are "Latin1 compatible", you probably meant "ASCII compatible". Latin1 defines characters up to 255, whereas ASCII only goes up to 127. There are tons of ASCII-compatible encodings, and very few Latin1-compatible ones.

Comment: Notably, UTF-8 is very commonly used, and is not Latin-1 compatible (but is ASCII compatible)

Comment: Sure, I meant 'first-128-characters-wise compatible'. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @StephenC not just in theory, as it turns out

Comment: By the way, FYI, UTF-8 will be the default encoding for most purposes in Java 18 and later. See [JEP 400](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400).

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy - The "in theory" is that your JVM needs to have a suitable encoder/decoder for the encoding.  It is not just a theory that `-Dfile.encoding=...` works if Java recognizes the encoding name that you gave.

Answer (score 1):

An experiment.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());
        byte[] bytes = "test".getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(bytes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

`java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 Test` produces the following:

```
UTF-8
116
101
115
116
```

`java -Dfile.encoding=cp1140 Test` (where cp1140 is a non-ASCII compatible encoding, an EBCDIC variant) outputs something that my terminal cannot decypher, but, if I use the same `cp1140` to decode it, it turns out to be

```
IBM01140
-93
-123
-94
-93
```

So yes, a non-ASCII encoding may be set as a default, and a JVM starts happily with it.

One takeaway is that it's not safe to use `String#getBytes()` even when you are sure you are always dealing with ASCII strings.

Another takeaway from my experiments is that `file.encoding` may be assigned any garbage, and in such case a JVM will not complain, but it will silently ignore the property:

```
$ java -Dfile.encoding=aaa Test
UTF-8
116
101
115
116
```

This is how it works with Java 1.8.0_161.

Java 11.0.6 does not seem to support cp1140 (it still uses UTF-8 even with `-Dfile.encoding=cp1140`).

Comment: For future reference it would be useful to also note which Java version you tested this with, as with Java 18 the behaviour will likely/possibly change, as Basil pointed out in a comment on the question.

Comment: @JoachimSauer you are right, I've added the information about Java version.